# R: Can you add a label to reactive ggplot without covering data points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing a shiny app that renders a ggplot from a user uploaded csv. I need to add a label on the graph. It doesn't matter where the label goes, as long as it doesn't cover up any data points. The reason I am having trouble is because the scale/distribution of the uploaded csv is unknown, so I don't know in advance where a good place to put the label is, and I do not know a way to make it move around to avoid overlapping with points.

What I have tried so far is extending the graph so that the x axis is 1 standard deviation larger than it needs to be so that I can put the label all the way to the right and assure that there will be no data points there to overlap. This works, but it is not very pleasing aesthetically.

Here is the code that I have:

```
df        # uploaded data frame
x1, x2    # columns of the data frame 

 ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x1, y=x2))+
        geom_point()+
        xlim(min(df$x1), max(df$x1)+sd(df$x1))+
        annotate(geom="label", x=max(df$x1)-sd(df$x1), y=min(df$x2), label="words"))
```

Comment: What about just `labs(title = "x", subtitle = "y", caption = "z")`?

Comment: I needed the label to be overlaid on top of the graph instead of anywhere around it that a caption can be placed. The ggrepel package as has allowed me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of potential solutions to this problem; perhaps the ggrepel package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) will do the trick? E.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  # arrange the df by your y variable
  arrange(desc(bill_length_mm)) %>% 
  # create a new variable (called "label_one_point")
  # and give the single highest y variable point a label
  mutate(label_one_point = ifelse(bill_length_mm == first(bill_length_mm),
                                  "PENGUINS!! \n(or whatever label you want)", NA)) %>% 
  # plot the thing
  ggplot(aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label_one_point),
                  # you can move the label closer or further away
                  point.padding = unit(20, "cm"),
                  # and you probably don't want a 'segment', so set this high
                  # a segment is a line attaching a geom_text to it's point
                  min.segment.length = unit(20, "cm"),
                  force_pull = 0.1, size = 5,
                  show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_light()
```

[image: example_1.png]

Comment: I did not know this package existed, but it is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I have accepted this as the answer to my question.